# Pushing MySQLi dynamic data into an array fails while everything else succeeds

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code to dynamically assign results from a MySQL database (assume all code prior is correct - because I do)

```
// Execute the query.
$statement->execute();

// Grab the dynamic number of results.
$statement->store_result();

$meta = $statement->result_metadata();
$data = array();
$refs = array();

while ($name = $meta->fetch_field()) {
  $refs[] =& $data[$name->name];
} // while ($name = $meta->fetch_field())

$meta->free_result();

call_user_func_array(array($statement, "bind_result"), $refs);
```

The problem occurs as soon as I do a `while ($statement->fetch())`.

The following code will print unique data (referred to as 'printer')

```
while ($statement->fetch()) {
  print print_r($data, true);
} // while ($statement->fetch())
```

However the following will print only the last database result, `$statement->num_rows` amount of times (referred to as 'pusher')

```
$array = array();

while ($statement->fetch()) {
  array_push($array, $data);
} // while ($statement->fetch())

print print_r($array, true);
```

Mimicking the answer given [on this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671490/php-mysqli-fetch-array-push-overrides-data) while doing the following returns the same result as the 'pusher' `while` loop.

```
$array = array();

while ($statement->fetch()) {
  $temp = $data;

  array_push($array, $temp);
} // while ($statement->fetch())

print print_r($array, true);
```

My question is, in the 'pusher' loop, why is all my of data overwritten, even when creating a new variable at the beginning of each loop, and how can I prevent this without doing something like `array_push($array, array("param1" => $data["param1"], "param2" => $data["param2"], ... "paramN" => $data["paramN"]))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bind\_result into an array PHP mysqli prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496994/bind-result-into-an-array-php-mysqli-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the following line you do not bind an array, you bind elements of that array.

```
call_user_func_array(array($statement, "bind_result"), $refs);
```

This is just a dynamic way of doing

```
$statement->bind_result($data['x'], $data['y'], ...);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$statement->bind_result($x, $y, ...);
```

The array is not a reference, but all the elements of the array are references. `var_dump($data)` shows:

```
array(2) {
  ["category_name"]=>
  &NULL
  ["id"]=>
  &NULL
}
```

When you push this array into a new array, you don't push the values, you push the references. Your `$array` array is then made up of a lot of arrays pointing to the same values in memory.

I talk about this problem in [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61612881/1839439), but the solution is to either use `get_result()` or dereference the values.

You can do so with a simple loop inside of your `while` loop. On each iteration of the `foreach` loop PHP will create a new zval container for the value. You can then push that value into a temporary array, which you later push into `$array`.

```
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        $temp[$key] = $val;
    }
    $array[] = $temp;
}
```